# How to improve my answer

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, quality-improvement, code-only-answers

Today I [answered the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65165779/1772898) *How to check if a website has HTTP/2 protocol support*. One of the reviewers was kind enough to leave a comment and add the link to [the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27780780). The comment says:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or
> request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their
> post.

How can I improve the answer?

Original version of the answer to "How to check if a website has HTTP/2 protocol support" for reference:

> ```
> % curl -vso /dev/null --http2 https://www.cloudflare.com/
> ....
> * ALPN, offering h2
> * ALPN, offering http/1.1
> ....
> ```

Comment: The review was incorrect. The correct action was "Looks OK" because code-only answers *are* answers. See: [Flag 'Try This: {code}' Answers as “Very Low Quality”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359)

Comment: If you want to improve your answer, then you should [include an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712) of your code. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

Comment: @double-beep Could you turn your two comments into an answer please? I would upvote. The comments section is meant to "ask for clarification or add more information", not to answer the question.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The reviewer chose to leave a canned comment. Confusingly, they chose to leave the wrong one. It is clear that you *were* intending to answer the question, so your answer should not have been flagged as such. You can go ahead and ignore that comment (in fact, I've deleted it).

However, there is one *major* way that your answer could be improved: **by adding a description of your code**. Tell us how it works and how it solves the problem.

A block of code, especially simple code, sometimes seems self-evident. Indeed, to some readers, it may be. But others may appreciate an explanation of the code. A good answer needs to have both.

In the case of that specific answer, it isn't even code that you've shared. It's actually a command that should be executed, followed by the output. Because there's no explanation, that isn't entirely clear, except to someone who already understands what you're trying to say. And, for obvious reasons, that is not the target audience for answers!

Comment: I have updated the answer as well.

Comment: @blueray That's a very good edit. Thanks for taking the time. I made some other improvements to the grammar and presentation. Looks like a good answer now!